# Textarea in Angular not displaying text

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

First of all, I am sorry if I sound silly, but I am new to Angular, so please understand.

I have a schema in the database and it consists of an answer field. The user fills the answer and submits so his answer gets added to the database.

Now when the user clicks on the Edit Answer button, the user is redirected to a new component.

In component.ts file, I have declared a global variable and I am sending its value in HTML . However, my text area appears blank when I use [(ngModel)] inside . And when I don't add [(ngModel)] in  then the text do appears.

Two things which I am trying to achieve:

1) Getting the text from a global variable in .ts file printed inside .

2) Update this text in  and store it back in the same or some other variable in .ts file.

```
//.html

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="answers">
<textarea name="ans" [(ngModel)]="ans" rows="5" class="form- 
control">
{{answers.data.answer}}</textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitAnswer(ans)">
Update Answer
</button>
</div>

// .ts

export class EditanswerComponent implements OnInit {
qaId: any;
question: any;
answers: any;
constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private apiService: ApiserviceService) {
console.log(this.route.snapshot);
}

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
this.qaId = params;
});

this.apiService.viewAnswerById(this.qaId.aId).subscribe(ansObj => {
console.log("Answer Object", ansObj);
this.answers = ansObj;
console.log(this.answers.data.answer);
});
}

submitAnswer(ans) {
this.answers = ans;
console.log(this.answers);
}
}
```

Comment: if this is representing ur answer ```answers.data.answer``` , then set it to your ngModel --> ```[(ngModel)]="answers.data.answer"``` And leave out the curly brackets (stringinterpolation) --> {{ answers.data.answer }}

Comment: @sagat Thanks. Its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `{{answers.data.answer}}` in the textarea :

```
<textarea name="ans" [(ngModel)]="ans" rows="5" class="form- 
control">
{{answers.data.answer}}</textarea>
```

Just binding to `NgModel` will work, If your model `ans` has any value, It will show up in the textarea.

```
<textarea name="ans" [(ngModel)]="ans" rows="5" class="form- 
    control"></textarea>
```

Or you can set `[(ngModel)]= "answers?.data.answer"` on text area:

```
<textarea name="ans" [(ngModel)]="answers?.data.answer" rows="5" class="form- 
    control"></textarea>
```

Comment: @NikhilArora, Great! Please accept the answer if it helped!